# How to use Kotlin Coroutines with Firebase Realtime Database and decide between LiveData and StateFlow for nested objects?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working on an Android project and want to use Kotlin Coroutines with Firebase Realtime Database. I plan to use addValueEventListener but I'm unsure whether to go with LiveData or StateFlow for handling nested objects. StateFlow seems more efficient, but I noticed it doesn't trigger the collector when the value of a child object changes. Any advice on the best approach for this scenario? Thanks

Right now I am doing this without Kotlin Coroutines:

```
   private var valueEventListener: ValueEventListener? = null

    private val foodItemLiveData = MutableLiveData<CustomResponse<List<FoodItem>>>()
    val foodItemList: LiveData<CustomResponse<List<FoodItem>>>
        get() = foodItemLiveData

       fun getFoodItemList() {
        foodItemLiveData.value = CustomResponse.Loading()
        valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val foodItemList: MutableList<FoodItem> = mutableListOf()
                for (foodItemSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val foodItem = foodItemSnapshot.getValue(FoodItem::class.java)
                    if (foodItem != null) {
                        foodItemList.add(foodItem)
                    }
                }
                foodItemLiveData.value = CustomResponse.Success(foodItemList)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                foodItemLiveData.value = CustomResponse.Error(databaseError.toException().message.toString())
            }
        }
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener as ValueEventListener)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get real-time updates from the Realtime Database, we usually use a [callbackFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) because it offers you a "synchronized" way to perform the call using the [Channel#trySend()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/) function. And in code, it will be:

```
fun getFoodItems() = callbackFlow {
    val listener = object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val foodItems = snapshot.children.map { foodItemSnapshot ->
                foodItemSnapshot.getValue(FoodItem::class.java)
            }
            trySend(Success(foodItems))
        }

        override fun onCancelled(e: DatabaseError) {
            Failure(e.toException())
        }
    }
    itemsRef.addValueEventListener(listener)
    awaitClose {
        itemsRef.removeEventListener(listener)
    }
}
```

However, we can also use an extension property called [snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/ktx/package-summary#(com.google.firebase.database.Query).snapshots()). So now, we no longer need to use a callbackFlow, we can only use this property which is of type a [`Flow<DataSnapshot>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html). In code, it will be as simple as:

```
fun getFoodItems() = itemsRef.snapshots.map { snapshot ->
    snapshot.children.mapNotNull { foodItemSnapshot ->
        foodItemSnapshot.getValue<FoodItem>()
    }
}
```

When it comes to LiveData, please notice that LiveData is a data holder class introduced as part of the [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture). It is designed to hold and observe data changes. This approach can be used in Java as well as in Kotlin. On the other hand, Flow is part of [Kotlin's Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) library and is designed for asynchronous stream processing of data. It allows you to receive multiple values over time.

If you consider trying to use [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), and if you want to read more regarding the ways in which we can perform Firebase asynchronous calls, then please check the following resource:

- [How to effortlessly get real-time updates from Firestore on Android?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-effortlessly-get-real-time-updates-from-firestore-on-android-bcb823f45f20)

Comment: Don't StateFlow and LiveData both do both of those things, holding and observing data changes, and receiving multiple values over time? Flow doesn't hold data, but StateFlow does. Aside from Flow having more useful operators, the main behavior differences seem to be that LiveData can only be changed and observed on the main thread and so intermediate values can never be missed by an observer, and StateFlow doesn't emit repeated values (based on `equals()` comparison).

Comment: Thanks, @Tenfour04 for the additional information.

Comment: Hey Usman. Did my answer help, can I help you with other information?